# Change the language back from Chinese to English on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

Tags: languages, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

My grandson used my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 and now the language is all in Chinese. What do I have to do to get it back to English as I do not read Chinese?

Comment: For all who answered the question, @Mike Powell does not read chinese, so I think he can't find the settings ^^

Answer (score 6):

Go to:

> `Settings > My device > Language and input > Language`

then set any language you want it to change the menu language. Should be similar to this, just find this icon and follow it step-by-step.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Follow exactly the same steps as shown. (Note: the text is in Japanese, but you could follow the icons and position of the menu)

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Well, this is Japanese, not Chinese. Might be still useful if people can follow it based on the location/symbols, not the text.

Comment: Dude i can't tell the difference between Chinese and Japanese. They look same to me. Lol

Answer (score -1):

you can also try go to MENU < SETTINGS < LOCALE AND TEXT < SELECT LOCALE and choose your language. For more details you check in support option of Samsung India site.

Comment: Yonk. Now again in Chinese, please – there are no English menus :)